# Bootstrap select not allowing to select everything

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap select. I have two options called "Connected" and "Detected". It's a multi select i.e I can use connected, detected or both.

This is the code:

**HTML**

> ```
> <select id="connectedDetected" class="selectpicker col-xs-4" multiple="multiple" data-live-search="true" title="Connected, Detected"/>
> ```

**Javascript:**

```
        var connectedDetected =
          [ {
              "key" : "connected",
              "title" : "Connected"
            }, {
              "key" : "detected",
              "title" : "Detected"
            }
          ],

          output = '';

          connectedDetected.forEach(function(tag){
              var selected = 'selected="true"';

              output += '<option value="'+ tag.key +'" '+selected+'>'+ tag.title +'</option>';
          });

        this.ui.connectedDetected.append(output);

        this.ui.connectedDetected.selectpicker({
          multiple:true,
          size: 2
        });
```

**Question:**

**How can I make atleast one option mandatory in bootstrap select?** I.e I don't want the user to deselect everything. **I want either both or one option (Connected or detected or both) checked?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```js
var connectedDetected =
          [ {
              "key" : "connected",
              "title" : "Connected"
            }, {
              "key" : "detected",
              "title" : "Detected"
            }
          ],

          output = '';

$(connectedDetected).each(function(i,j){
  output += "<option value='"+ j.key + "' selected>"+ j.title + "</option>";
});

$("#mySelect").html(output);

function check(){
  if($("#mySelect").find(":selected").length==0)
    $("#mySelect option:first").attr("selected","selected");

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
For to select multiple press and hold CTRL while clicking<br>
<select id="mySelect" multiple size=2 onchange="check()"></select>
  
 </body>
```